# Full width using enumerate within multicol

Tags: fullwidth

In my document, I need some text should be comes as full text width, i.e., `\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep`, for this I did some codes, which follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,multicol}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\setlength\textwidth{144truemm}
\setlength\marginparsep{5truemm}
\setlength\marginparpush{6\p@}
\setlength\marginparwidth{28truemm}

\newenvironment{splcolorshaded}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep%
\ifodd\c@page\hskip\marginparwidth\hskip\marginparsep\else%
\hskip-\iotextleftskip%
\hskip-\marginparwidth\hskip-\marginparsep\fi\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\definecolor{testcolor}{cmyk}{0,0.07,0.05,0}%

\newenvironment{testcolorenv}{\bgroup%
\colorlet{shadecolor}{testcolor}%
\setlength{\FrameSep}{14\p@}%
\begin{splcolorshaded}\vspace*{-1\FrameSep}\vspace*{-1.45\p@}\advance\hsize\marginparwidth\advance\hsize\marginparsep%%
\advance\hsize-2\FrameSep%
\fontsize{8.5}{12.75}\sf\selectfont%
\nopagebreak\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse\nopagebreak}{\par\vphantom{y}\vspace*{-1\FrameSep}\end{splcolorshaded}\egroup}%

\makeatother

This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)

\begin{testcolorenv}
This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item List the main assumptions of the kinetic
particle model.
Apply, analyse and interpret
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)
\end{enumerate}
\item Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)
\item Solids and liquids can’t be compressed very
much. It takes large forces to compress them
even slightly. What can you infer about the
microscopic nature of solids and liquids from their
incompressibility?
\item Gases are very compressible compared with solids
and liquids. Conclude what this says about the
microscopic nature of gases.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{testcolorenv}
\end{document}
```

If text comes then it came as `fullwidth`, but if I give `numbered list` within `multicols` environment, it won't come as `fullwidth`, how can I fix this?

Output is shown below for better understanding...[image]

Comment: What's not clear is whether your real document is in two column mode as an option of the document class, or only two columns locally through the `multicols` environment.

Comment: @Bernard my document is single column with some next needs to place as marginal notes. And some group of text should come in full width, i.e., text width is \textwidth+\marginparwidth

Comment: But why don't you interrupt the twocols environment to have your enumerate full width thereafter?

Comment: @Bernard that means twocols should treat the columnwidth as fullwidth divided by 2, i.e., \textwidth+\marginparwidth divide by 2, hope I'm clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `multicols` uses `\linewidth` instead of `\hsize`.  You should probably also set `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,multicol}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\setlength\textwidth{144truemm}
\setlength\marginparsep{5truemm}
\setlength\marginparpush{6\p@}
\setlength\marginparwidth{28truemm}

\newenvironment{splcolorshaded}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep%
\ifodd\c@page\hskip\marginparwidth\hskip\marginparsep\else%
\hskip-\iotextleftskip%
\hskip-\marginparwidth\hskip-\marginparsep\fi\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\definecolor{testcolor}{cmyk}{0,0.07,0.05,0}%

\newenvironment{testcolorenv}{\bgroup
\colorlet{shadecolor}{testcolor}%
\setlength{\FrameSep}{14\p@}%
\begin{splcolorshaded}\vspace*{-1\FrameSep}\vspace*{-1.45\p@}\advance\hsize\marginparwidth\advance\hsize\marginparsep%%
\advance\hsize-2\FrameSep%
\linewidth=\hsize%****************   this is the only change
\fontsize{8.5}{12.75}\sf\selectfont%
\nopagebreak\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse\nopagebreak}{\par\vphantom{y}\vspace*{-1\FrameSep}\end{splcolorshaded}\egroup}%

\makeatother

This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)

\begin{testcolorenv}
This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item List the main assumptions of the kinetic
particle model.
Apply, analyse and interpret
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is test for sublist. Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)
\end{enumerate}
\item Explain how the kinetic energy of a substance
changes as it goes from a solid to a liquid to a gas.
(You learnt about kinetic energy in Year 10.)
\item Solids and liquids can’t be compressed very
much. It takes large forces to compress them
even slightly. What can you infer about the
microscopic nature of solids and liquids from their
incompressibility?
\item Gases are very compressible compared with solids
and liquids. Conclude what this says about the
microscopic nature of gases.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{testcolorenv}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]